# How to edit this MySQL query to include an extra column with count and avg?

Tags: php, mysql

This query:

```
select p.visitor_id , p.url, avg(p.duration), count(*) as sum_pages
from pages p
where visitor_id = 1
group by p.visitor_id , p.url
having avg(p.duration) > (select avg(p2.duration)
                          from pages p2
                          where p2.visitor_id = p.visitor_id
                         );
```

produces this hypothetical table:

```
visitor_id ---- url ---- duration --- sum_pages
1 ------------ home ------- 5 ------- 20
1 ------------ about ------ 8 ------- 12
1 ------------ contact ---- 2 ------- 13
1 ------------ services --- 2 ------- 18
```

What it does: Takes the average duration number of the whole table, and checks if the average duration URL is greater. If yes, it displays the number.

I want to do the same thing and this time to add the pageviews. Each row is counted as a pageview.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want all vistor_id + url combinations where the duration is > avg and pageviews is > avg?  By average you mean the overall average for a person?

Comment: Can you elaborate *and this time to add the pageviews* in detail ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @PatrickSJ exactly that!

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I mean to further add the condition to the existing query

Comment: @EnexoOnoma, well you have a problem because the implied source data has no way to calculate an average pageview for a visitor_id + url.  You can get the total #of times it has been viewed, but to have an average you need to sum two or more numbers.  What 2+ numbers are to be summed?  I've setup a fiddle for you.  If you could play with it, maybe add some more data?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this but not sure about the performance of the query:

```
select
visitor_id, 
url,
sum(duration), 
avg(duration),
count(*) as sum_pages
from pages p 
where visitor_id='1' 
group by visitor_id,url
having sum(duration) > (select avg(duration)
                         from pages
                         where visitor_id=p.visitor_id
                       )
 and sum_pages > (select count(*)/(select count(distinct url) from pages where visitor_id=p1.visitor_id)
                   from pages p1
                  where p1.visitor_id=p.visitor_id
                  )
 ;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0b475/7/1)

Comment: it seems that you may made it work! but it lacks of performance.. is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: I don't think so. Because in order to calculate avg pageviews, it requires 3 different counts which you are not storing in your actual table anywhere.

Comment: I am calculating average pageviews in `having` clause using `(total no of rows for a vistior_id/no of distinct url for that visitor_id)`. And then comparing it with `sum_pages` of a particular `url`. If `sum_pages` > avg I've calculated, it'll display results for that `(visitor_id,url)` pair.